# Why I don't need to add prerequisite ".depend" in this make file?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a make file I wrote which represents a simple example of auto-detecting if a header file is changed using `.depend` generated by `gcc -MM -MF`.

Consider the following makefile: We have `main.c` and `factorial.h`

```
CC=gcc 
CFLAGS=-c -Wall  
OBJECTS=main.o 
SRCS=main.c 
EXECUTABLE=program

all: $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) 
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) -o $(EXECUTABLE)


.depend: $(SRCS)
    rm -f ./.depend
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -MM $^ -MF ./.depend;


sinclude .depend
#main.o: main.c factorial.h

clean:
    rm -rf *.o $(EXECUTABLE) .depend
```

This works fine and I want to know why!
The common sense is to write

`$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) .depend`

because we want to make sure the file `.depend` is there. However, it seems like omitting it works fine, too. Why? Also, I'd like to know what `include` (or `sinclude` in this case) actually does. I think: in our example,  `include .depend` would be replaced by
`main.o: main.c factorial.h`, but again the workflow doesn't make sense. Any experts?

Answer (score 1):

Make will automatically try to remake the target of an [`include` directive](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Remaking-Makefiles)

> [...]after reading in all makefiles, **make will consider each as a goal target and attempt to update it.**

The line `sinclude .depend` tells make "Read in `.depend`, don't quit if it fails, look for any matching rules, and remake `.depend` if it's out of date."

In any case you should create dependencies as a side effect of compilation, there's really no need for the extra step

```
target  := program
sources := main.c 
objs    := $(sources:.c=.o)
deps    := $(objs:.o=.d)

CPPFLAGS := -MMD -MP
CFLAGS   := -Wall  

$(target): $(objs) 
    $(LINK.o) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

clean: ; $(RM) $(target) $(objs) $(deps)

-include $(deps)
```

Comment: Thank you. When you say remake the target of an include directive does it mean "include .depend " will seek for the target named ".depend" and execute its instruction?

Comment: @Thenewstockton Exactly, but only after including the file itself, which allows for a makefile to contain a rule for remaking itself. Obviously that wouldn't work here because `.depend` won't exist the first time make is invoked.